# submit button not working after calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code on my cshmtl page. I have a checkbox asking user a question and based on that question, I am asking user to fill out one of the text box so I am making one of the text box required. Below is my code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form asp-action="Create">

    <input type="checkbox" id="FirstBox" />Is this test?
    <br />
    <input id="test1" class="form-control" />    <br />
    <input id="test2"   class="form-control" />
    <span id="lblMessage" style="display: none; color: red;">Please fill out at least one text box</span>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" id="myBtn1" onclick="Validate();return false;">Submit</button>

</form>



@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate() {
            var message = document.getElementById("lblMessage");a
            message.style.display = "none";
            var fb = document.getElementById("FirstBox");
            var sb = document.getElementById("test1");
            var tb = document.getElementById("test2");
            if (fb.checked) {
                if (fb.checked) {
                    if (sb.value == "" && tb.value == "")
                    message.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
       
    </script>
}
```

after putting the Validate function call on the submit button, the submit button stopped responding. It stopped redirecting to another page. If I remove the Validate() function from the Submit button then it start working.  Below is the code in my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
        }
```

below is the screen shot of my application:

[image]

below is the employee controller code:

```
namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add a disabled attribute to your submit button. Then set your checkboxes as radios so you get the benefit of adding a ***name*** attribute to both the yes and no radios, this way the two elements will toggle when one or the other are *selected*, then you only have to check for a validation once. Run `querySelectorAll()` on the radio button using their class and then add an event listener listening for an input. First time it fires, remove the disabled attribute from your submit button.

Comment: When you click submit button, you wanna call javascript function first then submit the form?

Comment: I am calling the Javascript function first and I can see the error message too, but after that the submit button just seems to be frozen. It does not seem to respond at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one variable which will track if the form is valid or not and depending on it you can return true/false to submit your form.

***Demo Code***:

```js
function Validate() {
  var flag = true; // added this variable
  var message = document.getElementById("lblMessage");
  message.style.display = "none";
  var fb = document.getElementById("FirstBox");
  var sb = document.getElementById("test1");
  var tb = document.getElementById("test2");
  if (fb.checked) {
    if (sb.value == "" && tb.value == "") {
      message.style.display = "block";
      flag = false; //added false if found empty
    }
  }
  return flag; //return true/false..
}
```

```html
<form asp-action="Create">

  <input type="checkbox" id="FirstBox" />Is this test?
  <br />
  <input id="test1" class="form-control" /> <br />
  <input id="test2" class="form-control" />
  <span id="lblMessage" style="display: none; color: red;">Please fill out at least one text box</span>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="myBtn1" onclick="return Validate();">Submit</button>
  <!--added return here -->

</form>
```

Comment: After making the above mentioned changes, the form submits irrespective of whether I fill out the text boxes or not. I can see the error displaying, but then the form submits right away. it didn't give me the chance to fill out the text boxes.

Comment: Hi @Anjali did you added `onclick="return Validate();"` to your submit button ?

Comment: Hi @Swati, Yes, I did.

Comment: I think something else might be causing it to submit . Are you seeing same behaviour in provided snippet which is added in answer ?

Comment: It could be, the issue was my page became unresponsive on chrome so I started debugging it on edge. I accepted/upvoted your answer. I think, I need to create a new page and just write this script. Thanks for all your help!